# identifying/tagging HTML elements in flask

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

A little background, the back end of this should receive a form and then populate a new list based on the filter from the post data.

Let's say I have markup like this

```
<form method="POST" action="/my/app/route/">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name:
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="text" name="NAME" maxlength="100" size="20" style="width: 90%;"
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
       Classes:
     </td>
     <td>
       <select multiple="true" name="CLASSES">
         <option>Painting Composition</option>
         <option>Analysis of Algorithms</option>
         <option>Game Design</option>
         <option>Assembly Language</option>
         <option>Pirate History</option>
       </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

this will show up as a text box and a select box. Now in my flask, I want to treat text boxes and select boxes differently; if something comes from a text box, I simply want to do an `in` statement. EG, `if (textbox): if row[k] not in filter_dict[k]: break`

```
   @app.route('/my/app/route/') 
   def filter_CSV(data):
      filter_dict = dict(request.form)
      return_list = []
      #row looks like this: {"NAME": string, "CLASSES": string}
      for row in data:
        for k, v in filter_dict.iteritems():
          # here is where the check for text box would come
          # else, do this stuff:
          row[k] = row[k].split(', ')
            if not set(row[k]).issuperset(set(filter_dict[k])):
              break
            return_list.append(row)
        return return_list
```

so how would one go about this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you make your example more clear? Something like, _The user selects "Painting Composition" and "Game Design", I want my view to be able to get variable "x" to store a list of..._ Use the actual example values in your description of what you want in your results.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look here at the Flask request object.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object)

You don't need to put the object into a dictionary like you're doing. You can just access NAME with: request.form['NAME']

Comment: yes, my goal is just to make it more arbitrary. I feel that hardcoding it will cause future problems, especially considering my actual program has many more fields than this example. It would be ideal to say that, if they typed in something to a text field, to interpret in a specific way

Comment: I don't believe that information is included in the http request. HOWEVER, if you use Flask-WTF: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ you will be able to define your forms in a more structured way. This would then allow you to check the class (where you make your forms) to check what kind of form it is.